# Removing css property that is applied to all elements with javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I'm building a website which mainly runs on WordPress. However, some pages I've coded myself in HTML/CSS/Javacsript, which I upload via a Wordpress plugin. The problem with this is that Elementor, a plugin, is adding css styles to the page. I want to delete those with a Javascript function on page load. Probably a stupid way of working as I'm new to coding, so any suggestion on this way of working is welcome.

Specifically the following style is added to the page:

`*, *::before, *::after {* box-sizing: border-box;}`

I know the code `element.removeProperty('box-sizing').` However, the box-sizing applies to all elements * and I don't know how to select this 'element'. `*.removeProperty('box-sizing')` is obviously not working. Could anyone help me with this Javscript function that I will run on page load? Thanks a lot.

```
function remove_box_sizing(){
    .removeProperty('box-sizing') 
}
```

Comment: Can your file include CSS that gets applied _after_ Elementor's styles, which can then re-set `box-sizing`?  Failing that' maybe just build your page with those styles in mind.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a stylesheet where you override these rules with !important